# Assertion Error, python

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to make a tool for exporting pdfs from a directory: I found one online but it was very slow, I am trying to code it more efficiently. I am getting an AssertionError and I am not sure how to fix it.

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\jds\Desktop\MXD_Export_Test"

folderPath = r"C:\Users\jds\Desktop\MXD_Export_Test"

mxdList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd")

for mxd in mxdList:  
    saveName = mxd.split(".")[0] + ".pdf"
    savePath = os.path.join(folderPath, saveName) 
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, savePath)
```

Error =

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in **main**.**dict**
  File "C:\Users\jds\Desktop\Scripts\Export_PDF_From_Directory.py", line 14, in 
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, savePath)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 1148, in ExportToPDF
    assert isinstance(map_document, MapDocument)
AssertionError

Comment: Can you edit your question an add the actual error message?

Answer (score 3):

Your variable mxd as it stands is not a MapDocument object, it's just a path.  You have to maybe add a line under the loop:

```
for mxd in mxdList:  
    md = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd)
    saveName = mxd.split(".")[0] + ".pdf"
    savePath = os.path.join(folderPath, saveName) 
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(md, savePath)
```

See the documentation here: [ExportToPDF](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttopdf.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I have figured it out, with help form Jvhowube.

Not only did I need a map object, but the map object needed to be the full file path.

```
for mxd in mxdList:
    fullPath = os.path.join(folderPath, mxd)
    md = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullPath)
    saveName = mxd.split(".")[0] + ".pdf"
    savePath = os.path.join(folderPath, saveName)
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(md, savePath)
```